# Correct timing for temporary vertical adjustments?

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, vertical-spacing, output-routine

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
page 1 - textheight shall be normal and is ok.
\newpage
\begingroup
\textheight=5cm
page 2 - textheight shall be 5cm but is normal.
\newpage 
page 3 - textheight shall be 5cm and is ok.
\newpage
\endgroup
page 4 - textheight shall be normal but is 5cm
\newpage
page 5 - textheight shall be normal and is ok.
\end{document}
```

With exmple above:

- Why is height of page 2 not 5cm but "normal"?
- Why is height of page 4 not "normal" but 5cm?

How to do correct timing for temporary vertical adjustments?

Answer (score 1):

The timing for vertical adjstments is correct.

But in LaTeX 2ε besides `\textheight` you need to take into account other parameters as well, e.g., `\@colht`, `\@colroom` and `\vsize`.

If interested look them up in [source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

The following example is not suitable for `\twocolumn` and the like.

You might be interested in how things are implemented in the package [geometry](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
page 1 - textheight shall be normal and is ok.
\newpage
\begingroup
\textheight=5cm
\csname @colht\endcsname=\textheight
\csname @colroom\endcsname=\textheight
\vsize=\textheight
page 2 - textheight shall be 5cm and is 5cm and is not normal.
\newpage
page 3 - textheight shall be 5cm and is ok.
\newpage
\endgroup
\csname @colht\endcsname=\textheight
\csname @colroom\endcsname=\textheight
\vsize=\textheight
page 4 - textheight shall be normal and is normal ant not 5cm
\newpage
page 5 - textheight shall be normal and is ok
\end{document}
```